# zero padding zoom fourier

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, octave

I'm trying to implement a zero padding zoom using fourier. 
I'm using octave and I can't add zeros around my matrix.
The result (after inverse fourier transformation) is very dark.

**My goal:**
[image: My goal]

**My code:**

```
I=double(imread('montagne.jpeg'));
I = I/255;
%%scaling factor
facteur = 4;
[m,n,r] = size(I);
H=fft2(I);
H = fftshift(H);
%%the new image
B = zeros(facteur*m,facteur*n,3);
%%try to add zeros around my matrix
%% r : rgb channels
for r=1:3
  for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
      B(i+((facteur*m)/4),j+((facteur*n)/4),r) = H(i,j,r);
    end
 end
end

%% show the image
B= ifftshift(B);
final = ifft2(B);
figure;
imshow(final);
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use for-loops to copy matrices. I would try something like:

```
I = im2double (imread ('IMG_2793.JPG'));
facteur = 4; %%scaling factor
[m, n, r] = size (I);
H = fftshift (fft2 (I));
B = zeros(facteur*m, facteur*n, 3);

ms = round (m * (facteur/2 - 0.5));
ns = round (n * (facteur/2 - 0.5));

B(ms:(m+ms-1), ns:(n+ns-1), :) = H;
final = abs (ifft2 (ifftshift (B)));
figure;
imshow(final * facteur^2);
```

EDIT:

Btw, there is also the function `padarray` which does what you want:

```
octave:1> padarray (magic(3), [1, 1])
ans =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   8   1   6   0
   0   3   5   7   0
   0   4   9   2   0
   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work... The image is still dark and if I add "facteur^2" it's too bright.

Comment: I tried it too and it works. So perhaps you have to upload your image or adapt the factor yourself